# How do I use the xml package to new line the closing tag when element is empty

Tags: xml, go

My goal is to break closing tag to new line when element is empty, and use Go xml package.

Also I want to indent the end tag to the same depth as the start tag when the element is empty, regardless of the nested depth.

> go version go1.15.2 darwin/amd64

**want**

```
<aaa>
  <bbb>
  </bbb>
</aaa>
```

However, Go xml EncodeElement will generate closing tag without line breaks if the content is empty.

https://play.golang.org/p/fa76aeZ9Xss

```golang
func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    e := xml.NewEncoder(&b)
    e.Indent("", "  ")
    
    aaa := xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "aaa"}}
    e.EncodeToken(aaa)
    
    bbb := xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "bbb"}}
    e.EncodeToken(bbb)
    e.EncodeToken(bbb.End())
    
    e.EncodeToken(aaa.End())

    // execute
    e.Flush()
    fmt.Println(b.String())
}
```

```
<aaa>
  <bbb></bbb>
</aaa>
```

I tried insert `\n` at `<bbb>`. But `</bbb>` is not indented.

```golang
    c := xml.CharData([]byte("\n"))
    e.EncodeToken(c)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ekShCtPXBWR

```
<aaa>
  <bbb>
</bbb>
</aaa>
```

Also I want the closing tag to be indented in the same depth as the starting tag, no matter how nested.

```
<xxx> 
  <aaa>
  <yyy>
    <bbb>
    </bbb>
  </yyy>
  </aaa>
</xxx>
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Self-solved based on the information received.

Save the number of times the EncodeToken was called because you need to know how many spaces to indent.

```golang
    aaa := xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "aaa"}}
    e.EncodeToken(aaa)
    cnt++
    e.EncodeToken(aaa.End())
```

Insert an indent using the saved count.

```golang
        // insert new line, and indent
        c := "\n"
        for i := 0; i < cnt; i++ {
            c = c + "  "
        }
        e.EncodeToken(xml.CharData([]byte(c)))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/2-5qEHjT2B4

thank you.